# Debian 9.1 does not connect to another network if I'm connected already

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

I installed the new Debian 9.1 and I realized a problem which I believe to be a bug. When I'm connected to a network, whatever it is, and I try to select a new one, it will not connect. It will try for several seconds, fail and connect back to the previous one.

For me to be able to connect to a new one, I must forget all the networks and select the new one, and again enter the password.

I don't know if it would be a bug, and if I could officially report it.

Answer (score 0):

You should [report a bug to debian](https://wiki.debian.org/reportbug) , there are 3 open bugs for `network-manager` and 1 bug for `wpasupplicant` package:

```
$apt-listbugs list wpasupplicant network-manager

Retrieving bug reports... Done
Parsing Found/Fixed information... Done
grave bugs of wpasupplicant (-> ) <Outstanding>
 b1 - #849122 - With 2.6-2 i dont have the wifi adapter in the (network-manager) list available.
serious bugs of wpasupplicant (-> ) <Outstanding>
 b2 - #849077 - wpasupplicant: [Regression] Updating wpasupplicant makes not possible to connect to encrypted WiFi
 b3 - #849875 - broadcom-sta-dkms: Wifi association took too long, failing activation
serious bugs of network-manager (-> ) <Outstanding>
 b4 - #870171 - WPA usage error: Invalid passphrase character
Summary:
 wpasupplicant(3 bugs), network-manager(1 bug)
```

The [#870171](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=870171) describe the same bug

> I could not figure out what is going on. I selected an AP which has been
>   working fine for months, and suddenly NM switched me to another AP
>   (which works partly since it is far away and reception quality is bad).

Apparently the problem come from `wpa_supplicant` package.(awaiting the confirmation from report bug reply)

a quick fix:

Disable network-manager or wicd

Create a separate `wpa_supplicant.conf` file for every Access point

To switch between SSID , kill the runing `wpa_supplicant` process then connect from the terminal through `wpa_supplicant`.